# C# json file based database

Tags: c#, .net, json

For my very basic application, I am planning to design/use json-file based structure.

Simply, application is very similar to a rss reader. So data security is not a big concern.

There will be categories like news, sports, tech and media. I am planning to save information/objects under files like 
media-todaysdate.json, so I can iterate through files by using date stamp.

Since files will be separated by dates I would not expect huge file sizes to create memory problem.

My question is that is there any framework that will help me to CRUD json files?

Or is there any easier way to manage information like mine?

Comment: A little unclear what you are asking, but if you just want to create classes based on JSON, there is a great little tool called [JSON 2 CSharp](http://json2csharp.com/).  It will take JSON and create class signatures for them.

Comment: An easier way to manage information would be .. to use an *existing* database. (Databases deal with information; and some expose this via JSON.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at Rob Conery's Biggy project.

https://www.infoq.com/news/2014/03/Biggy-Intro

It's a file-based store for JSON.